# Recursive function how to preservce the value within function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which loops over the product `categories` array where each category may have `children` array which contains `sub-categories` and each sub-category may also have children upto nth level

I have the `categories` array and `category_id` which I want to search my function looksl ike

```
  findCategory( categories, category_id) {
    let category;
    for( let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++ ) {

      if( categories[ i ].id === category_id ) {
        category  = categories[ i ];
        break;
      }

      if( !category && categories[ i ].children ) {
        this.findCategory( categories[ i ].children, category_id )
      }
    }
    return category
  }
```

It always return null, even it if it finds the category. What I am doing false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a found result in the loop as well.

You could add a default array for categories, which is important for not given children.

```
function findCategory(categories = [], category_id) {
    let category;
    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].id === category_id) {
            return categories[i];
        }
        if (category = this.findCategory(categories[i].children, category_id)) {
            return category;
        }
    }
}
```